# leaflet and shiny html widget wrongly rendered

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am recently learning leaflet for R. At first everything was okay, I modified the code and run my app back and forth.

But after one certain modification, I found my leaflet html widget could not be correctly rendered and I wasn't sure what I've done...

Even if I cleared the working directory, copied the whole [tutorial code](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) and ran that app, the html widget still skewed to the top of the canvas.

The inspector shows a warning and a fail.

[image: screenshot]

After googling some solution, I managed to solved the fail by adding `tags$head(tags$link(rel="shortcut icon", href="#"))` in UI section.

But the problem still came up. :((

I don't know how to trace the warning, `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

I've tried to reinstall my Rstudio and R but still no use.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

--- update ---

I found the code doing fine in RStudio viewer, but when I open in browser, the problem shows up.

Here's the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  p(),
  actionButton("recalc", "New points")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  points <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
    cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
        options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      ) %>%
      addMarkers(data = points())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can you post your `r` code which is causing the error?

Comment: @SymbolixAU I've added the `r` code. The code is copied from the tutorial github page. I found that the code runs fine in RStudio viewer, only render weird when opening in browser. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: I don't seem to have your issue. Is it simply that you need to set the `height` parameter in the `leaflet()` call - like this : `leafletOutput("mymap", height = "800px")` ?

Comment: @SymbolixAU I tried that, but it's bad luck. I still don't know why Chrome comes out with those fail and warning or how to fix it. But since everything is good in RStudio, I use `options(shiny.launch.browser = .rs.invokeShinyWindowViewer)` to force the map open in RStudio build-in viewer so that I can continue my project.. Maybe there was extension that conflict to Shiny. I will uninstall my chrome and see if the problem is solved.